# Simple VBA code with Range("A1:B3").Sort does not work with cells including formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A1:B3").Sort Key1:=Range("A1:A3"), Order1:=Descending, Header:=x1No
End Sub
```

However, cells A1 to A3 have formulas (eg. A1 `=C1` etc.), and this does not seems to work with my macro. I am not very familiar with coding and have tried to find a simple solution, but is there? I found an example which sets a targetRange and then specified this range to cells with formulas, but could not get it to work in my code.

Comment: The correct arguments are: `Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo`. Note that is XLNO and not X1NO.

Answer (score 0):

My simple suggestion would be to copy and pastespecial to a display sheet and sort your data on the display sheet. Or pastespecial to a new column and sort that.

example of pastespecial to another sheet in same workbook:
put the copy and paste on separate lines

```
wsSource.Range("B" & i & ":" & "C" & i).Copy 'Copy cells Bi and Ci
wsReceiver.Range("A" & j & ":" & "B" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

wsReciever is a variable that can be replaced with a know sheet name, the same with the letter j in the range.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, for some reason my Excel 2016 stops working if I try to use the Range.Copy method. This makes it a lot more complicated.. I don't know why it stops working, quick search did not bring any results about similar problems.

Comment: Sorry about that Maarit, I should have given you the full copy paste example.